# ReactJS Children Equivalent in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I've done quite a lot of ReactJS in the past.

I remember we had this awesome props called `props.children` to refer to any arbitrary amount of children that can be nested into a Component.

What is the equivalent of this in Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

You decide! You can use the following for instance:

```
class MyWidgetWithChildren extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyWidgetWithChildren(this.children);

      final List<Widget> children;

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) => DecoratedBox(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
            child: Column(children: children),
     );
}
```

An other way would be : Column(children: [Text('My children'), ...children);

Other widgets support displaying children and not child:

ListView (used when you want to be able to scroll), Column, Row (X-axis), Wrap (like a css flexbox with wrap :)) , Slivers (but that's another story :D, those are for more complex scrolling behaviour)